# confirm box multiple time after delete item - ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a menu in side of page, and this menu has many items to navigate.
Well, in a admin page, I have a table to manage those items.
When I delete an item in table (the delete was made in ajax), the item is deleted in table and menu side. I used the function load to load items in menu. But when I remove items two or more times, appears many confirm popup according the quantity of elements removed.

[image]
See the image. When I click in delete button, this item is removed in database and the table remove the item. When I delete an item for the first time, it show the confirm pop up one time and remove the item. Until here, thats correct. But when I delete the second, third ou more items, the confirm popup keeps active and appears many times according quantity of elements removed. Where is the mistake?

Menu Code:

```
echo '<div id="slide-out" class="side-nav sn-bg-4 fixed mdb-sidenav">
            <ul id="menu_ul" class="custom-scrollbar list-unstyled" style="max-height:100vh;">
                <!-- Side navigation links -->
                <li>
                    <ul id="side-menu" class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
                    <li id="home" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect" href="/admin/view/main.php"><img src="/imgs/icones/ic_home.png">Home</a></li>';

    foreach ($Menu_array as $valor)
    {

        echo '<li id='. $valor->getCategoria()->getCat_id() .' class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom'. $menu_filhos .'"><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect '"><img style="margin-right:10px; vertical-align: text-bottom; text-align:left" src="'.$valor->getCategoria()->getCat_img().'">'. $valor->getCategoria()->getCat_nome().'</a>';

            $array_SCat = [];
            $array_SCat = $valor->getlist_SCat();

            if((count($valor->getlist_SCat())) > 0)
            {
                echo '<div class="collapsible-body">
                        <ul class="sub-menu">';

                foreach($array_SCat as $val)
                {
                    echo '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page '"><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect" id='.$val->getSCat_id().' href="'.$variaveis->getDominio().'/'.$variaveis->getNome_site().'/admin/view/ld.php?id_cat='.$valor->getCategoria()->getCat_id().'&id_subcat='.$val->getSCat_id().'">'.$val->getSCat_nome().'</a></li>';
                }
                    </ul>
                </div>';
            }
        }
    }
        echo '</ul>
        </li>
        <!-- /. Side navigation links -->
        </ul>
    </div>';
```

The table code to delete item:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
         <tr>
              <td><a id="deleteItem" name="'.$val->getSCat_id().'">Delete</a></td>
         </tr>
```

ajax code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#deleteItem", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var idItem = $(this).attr('name');
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

    if (confirm('Deseja excluir o item?')) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/control/ajax/remove.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id: idItem},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response) {

                var result = $.trim(response);

                if(result === "success") {

                    $tr.find('td').fadeOut(800,function(){ 
                        $tr.remove();
                    });

                    $("body").load('#slide-out');

                } else if(result === "error") {

                    alert("Error.");

                }

            }

        });

    }

});
```

Notice I did this in ajax:

```
$("body").load('#slide-out');
```

The body calls the menu id slide-out to load.

Comment: Could you post more of the menu HTML? The value of the `name` attribute is odd, and I suspect your problems may begin there. Next, you should implement an `error` handler in case the server isn't returning a 2xx response, and alert/console.log the error.

Comment: @jeff_mcmahan I've posted the menu code. Thank you for attention.

Comment: @jeff_mcmahan I've implemented the error handler but the error is not considered. Don't execute the error handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change attribute **id** for "deleteItem" to class.
Here places:

#### Markup

```
<td><a class="deleteItem">Delete</a></td>
```

#### JS

`$(document).on("click", ".deleteItem", function(e) {});`

Comment: I solved my problem with this code: $(".deleteItem").unbind("click").click(function (e) {